# Schedule php script every hour, half hour, and 15 minutes Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, cron

I have three different php files which I want to schedule every:

- hour,
- half hour,
- 15 minutes.

Can anybody show me how is it possible to do that in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can edit `/etc/crontab:`

```
*/15 * * * * php every15minutes_file.php
*/30 * * * * php every30minutes_file.php
 0   * * * * php every1hour_file.php #it will run on full hour
```

You can also explore https://crontab.guru to understand it all better